# CI no host, não funciona

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-404

Tenho o Xampp instalado e localmente meu CRUD Code Igniter funciona.

No host, no subdomínio está dando *404 page not found*. Subi a pasta toda para um subdomínio. O subdomínio, criou uma pasta que nomeei como dez. Abaixo dela a estrutura é idêntica a estrutura local.

Já fiz:

- Troquei a configuração do database.php
- Troquei a configuração do config.php alterando esse item: `$config['base_url'] = '/dez/';`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase dez/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

- Já troquei todos os nomes dos *Controller* e *Model* (colocando a primeira letra em maiúscula).
- Já troquei `'$config['base_url'] = '/dez/';`  por `'$config['base_url'] = '/';`
- E `'$config['base_url'] = 'dez/';` por `'$config['base_url'] = '/dez';`
- Dentro do `.htacess` já troquei `RewriteBase dez/` por `RewriteBase`

No `routes.php` ----> `$route['default_controller'] = 'Dashboard';`

Então, no *Dashboard*:

```
<?php
  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Dashboard extends MY_Controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();      
    }
    function index($indice=null)
    { ......
```

Dentro de `MY_Controller` :

```
<?php 

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();

            $logado = $this->session->userdata("logado");

            if ($logado != 1) 

                redirect('/Login');             
       }
}
```

Então, no navegador digito o nome do subdomínio `'sie'` e aparece https://sie.dezenvolvesolucoes.com.br/dez/Login e a mensagem do CI *404 Page Not Found*

Fiz um teste e troquei `Dashboard extends MY_Controller` por `CI_Controller`. 
Então, é "montada" a página inicial, porém sem formatação do layout (css, js..). Verifico o código fonte da página (sem formatação de layout) e vejo os links para os arquivos `.css`, `js` ..

```
src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.min.js">
```

E quando clico neles, *page not found*. Vou ao CPanel e procuro pelos arquivos `.css` e `js`, todos existem.

O atual `.htacess`, é um exemplo que busquei aqui nesse link: https://gist.github.com/keithmorris/3023560

Nada....

Comment: Dica para a vida: antes de vírgula e depois de abrir o parentese, `(`, não existe espaço em branco. A pontuação não é para deixar o texto mais "bonito".

Comment: Remova o `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` e o `</IfModule>`, salve o htaccess, se der erro 500 é porque seu servidor esta sem esse modulo, ai vc ou ativa no cpanel (se tiver cpanel) ou solicita para o suporte técnico ativar ... Se não der erro 500 então o problema realmente é mais obscuro.

Comment: "Sir" Anderson Carlos Woss, acho que o 'Sir' não teve a percepção de que eu estou há dias tentando resolver esse problema. Sei muito bem usar a nossa língua.Como descrevi na pergunta, mesmo com o comando CTRL+K ,o código (olha ,com acento no primeiro ó ...)não ficava formatado.Então postei rápido.E agora,vou testar a dica do Guilherme Nascimento que foi direto ao objetivo desse fórum.Tentei mandar essa mensagem no privado mas não sei onde posso fazer isso.

Comment: Sobre a formatação, pode ler mais em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Obrigado, darei uma lida nesse HELP.

Answer (score -1):

Essa foi a solução :

1 - no .htacess onde estava  RewriteBase /dez eu troquei para  RewriteBase

2 - no config.php $config['base_url'] = '/';